Risk score calculation from coxph regression with multiple imputation dataset
I am conducting survival analysis on a dataset with less than 5% MCAR data. I have performed multiple imputation on this dataset and now I want to run the Cox proportional hazards model (coxph) in R. After that, I plan to compute pooled risk scores.
Could you give me some hints to achieve this?
